# Linking error while using htmlcxx with dev-cpp

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I have small program using htmlcxx but when I try building the code it gives linker error.
I just downloaded the htmlcxx.084.zip, unzipped it and placed it in Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\htmlcxx. The code does not give any build error but the linking fails.

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom::parseTree(std::string const&)' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `htmlcxx::HTML::operator<<(std::ostream&, tree<htmlcxx::HTML::Node, std::allocator<tree_node_<htmlcxx::HTML::Node> > > const&)' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `htmlcxx::HTML::Node::parseAttributes()' 
  [Linker error] undefined reference to `vtable for htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom' 
  ld returned 1 exit status 
  [Build Error]  [test.exe] Error 1
```

Am I missing something in the Makefile or the something is missing in the lib path.?

```
CPP = g++.exe
CC = gcc.exe
WINDRES = windres.exe
OBJ = tree_test.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ = tree_test.o $(RES)
LIBS = -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" -lwinmm -lgdi32
INCS = -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"
CXXINCS = -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2" -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"
BIN = test.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS)
CFLAGS = $(INCS)
RM = rm -f
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o "test.exe" $(LIBS)
```

Comment: Maybe if you post the makefile it will be easier to figure out the problem...

Comment: The Makefile is auto generated by the IDE                                    
CPP  = g++.exe
CC   = gcc.exe
WINDRES = windres.exe
OBJ  = tree_test.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = tree_test.o $(RES)
LIBS =  -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" -lwinmm -lgdi32  
INCS =  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include" 
CXXINCS =  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include" 
BIN  = test.exe
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS)  
CFLAGS = $(INCS)  
RM = rm -f
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
 $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o "test.exe" $(LIBS)

Comment: Actually the htmlcxx zip file I downloaded has everything for the include path, I think I need to build the same to create the .lib or .a file but I am wondering how to do it.     I downloaded the htmlcxx from http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlcxx/

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here: [tag:dev-c++].

Comment: And since i dont thing the OP is going to read it: A horrible, outdated IDE using a horrible outdated version of the GCC compiler. Dev-C++ was buggy and lacked major features when it was last updated *in 2005*. The situation has not improved just because the code has gone unmodified for 6 years. It is bundled with GCC 3.4 by default, which is just as old. ** Do not use **;