# htmlcxx0.84 compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, html-parsing

I try to use `htmlcxx` to parse a webpage. The problem is, the example isn't compileable .

I am getting this when I run `g++ webscrsp.cpp`:

```
/tmp/ccHiUM6o.o: In function `main':
webscrsp.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `htmlcxx::HTML::ParserSax::parse(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
webscrsp.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `htmlcxx::HTML::operator >&, tree > > const&)'
/tmp/ccHiUM6o.o: In function `htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom::ParserDom()':
webscrsp.cpp:(.text._ZN7htmlcxx4HTML9ParserDomC1Ev[htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom::ParserDom()]+0x22): undefined reference to `vtable for htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom'
/tmp/ccHiUM6o.o: In function `htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom::~ParserDom()':
webscrsp.cpp:(.text._ZN7htmlcxx4HTML9ParserDomD1Ev[htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom::~ParserDom()]+0x16): undefined reference to `vtable for htmlcxx::HTML::ParserDom'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my code is

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include </home/lubhavan/htmlcxx-0.84/html/ParserDom.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace htmlcxx;

    int main()
    {
      string html ="<html > <head> <title > hi  iam  titile </title> </head> <body> <p>               what  can i do </p> </body> </html>";
    HTML::ParserDom parser;
     tree<HTML::Node> dom = parser.parseTree(html) ;
     cout << dom <<endl;

     cout << endl;
     return 0;
     }
```

Please help me as I have to do it very soon. I am unable to get the fault ...

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking error while using htmlcxx with dev-cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300828/linking-error-while-using-htmlcxx-with-dev-cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entire command line is

```
g++ webscrsp.cpp
```

then you will get linker error because you don't link with the library which contain the actual code.

You have to do something like this:

```
g++ webscrsp.cpp -L/path/to/library -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/library -lname_of_library
```

In the above command line example, `/path/to/library` is the path to a file named `libXXX.a`, where `XXX` is the `name_of_library`.

In your case, you should look somewhere in `/home/lubhavan/htmlcxx-0.84/` to find a file that starts with `lib` and ends in `.a`. The `/path/to/library` is the path where that file is. The `name_of_library` is the name of the file without the leading `lib` and trailing `.a`.

Comment: there is no file with .a extension but there are somefiles which starts with lib and have .la or .so extensions...

Comment: @puneet The `.so` file is also a library, but one that is dynamically linked to your application. It works the same, use `-L` to set the path to where the library is, and `-l` (lower case L) to name the library you want to link (without `lib` and `.so`.)

Comment: @ Joahhim Pileborg   thank you sooooo much it worked  :)

but i have 1 more question do i have to add this library path n libname everytime i have to run teh program

Comment: @puneet Updated my answer to include another command line argument, that is used to set the runtime path for the executable.